# mediaelement.js I can't see video preview

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, preview, mediaelement.js

I can see video preview on the mediaelementjs.com website, I mean the image I see when the player has been loaded and it's still stopped, but using the same video file on my mediaelement.js installation using drupal module I only see a black background with the big play on it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Firefox. Worked fine in Safari.  Took out `preload="true"` and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I took out the preload="none" and the poster image showed up. must be a bug.